# How to use the values inside react native geolocation function at outside of it in react?

Tags: react-native, geolocation, jsx

How can I use the output of this component function outside its scope?

```
const abc = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
            // console.log({latitude, longitude})   this log gives the correct results
          });          
    }
```

I want to use `latitude` and `longitude` values outside the function, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make `abc` return a `Promise` that contains the latitude and longitude.

```
const abc = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
            resolve({latitude, longitude});
        });          
    });
}
```

then you can use it to save some state in a component:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const coords = await abc();
    setLocation(coords);
  });

  return ... // use `location` in some components here
}
```

Note that the above code may have a typo. I didn't run this example.

Comment: WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Promises must be constructed via new
TypeError: Promises must be constructed via new

Comment: I have little knowledge about promises, now looking, taking the values asynchronously is the main point as I understood, since when the app launch the coordinate values are undefined and throws error

Comment: This code works, but the point is to use the latitude and longitude value outside. When I write --> console.log(callABC().coords.latitude)  then the log output is "undefined". How can I use the output outside? I mean inside a mapview for example.

Comment: ``` async function callABC() {
  const coords = await abc();
 return coords;
}
```

Comment: Or define out a state variable, const [myCoords, setMyCoords]= useState({}); and on callABC function change return coords by setMyCoords(coords).